# Where is the graphical UI layout on Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, plugins, eclipse-adt

This is my first time writing Android app. When I downloaded the ADT bundle for the first time, everything went as planned according to the tutorial I followed. I was able to connect to my device and run my "hello world" app. Then, I closed Eclipse and later I came back to play around with Eclipse ide.

Now, I don't see any activity layout at all. I deleted my previous projects and created a new project hoping to see the activity layout or GUI for my device. I can't find it. I was planning on adding buttons or labels.

All I see is this message in the bottom:

**This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in**

So, how do you enable or bring back the Activity layout.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you create an Android Project? res\layout\ holds layout files - here you can switch to the design view.

Comment: @M.Bennett I just clicked on activity_main.xml file and I see nothing in the workspace but palette and other stuff.

Comment: Got Teamviewer installed? Or post a screenshot...

Comment: I added the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You need to update your ADT Plugin in your Android SDK Manager to solve this problem.

These tools should be up to date

Comment: So, do I need to run SDK manager and update the plugin that way? There are bunch of items listed in the box. What do I exactly check and initiate update process on the SDK manager.exe?